# which version of payara or glassfish should I use with jdk 14?

Tags: glassfish, payara, java-14

Which version of payara or glassfish should I use with jdk 14?
I've already tried glassfish 5.1.0 and payara 5.201.

Comment: As far as I know the highest supported version for Payara is JDK11.

Comment: so I should use netbeans 11.0 , jdk 11 and payara 5.194?

Comment: 5.201 should also work with JDK11.

Comment: @ChristophJohn I've also tried that but I'm getting this error: Error: 
Could not find or load main class Files\payara5\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\payara5\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

Both server support Jdk 11. There isn't clear information available about Jdk 14 yet.

1. Payara
   [Offical Reference](https://blog.payara.fish/jdk-11-support-available-in-payara-platform-194)

> With much excitement from users, JDK 11 support has been in technical preview since 5.192.

2. Glassfish
   [Official Reference](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/releases/6.0.0/plan)

> GlassFish 6.0.0 will support JDK 11+. Support for JDK 8 is not a goal for GlassFish 6.0.0